# Why my pidgin status message is not synced with gmail / gtalk?

Tags: pidgin

im using pidgin as my im client, and its very nice, i have this problem, if i set status message in pidgin, those message i set within pidgin is not showing on the gtalk client or gmail.

but with digby it was ok, but with pidgin how can i set this?

Comment: Because it is Pidgin. Seriously, Pidgin has its own armada of bugs. Try Miranda, Trillian, and the other million avaliable clients. Sadly Pidgin is like this (I also use it that's why I say this.)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there was a patch released that solves this issue before you even asked this question.
http://developer.pidgin.im/attachment/ticket/4509/gtalk-sharedstatus.patch

I'm not certain if it works with Pidgin 2.7.7, but I'm trying it out now. Perhaps someone more knowledgeable in the field of applying patches would experience more success here.

http:// developer.pidgin.im/ticket/11433